# Can I add class template to tuple?

Tags: c++, class, templates, tuples

I'm trying to add class template to tuple

These are my classes:

```
class Parent {
  // ...
}

class Child1 : public Parent {
  // ...
}

class Child2 : public Parent {
  // ...
}
```

My purpose is to add class like this way:

```
v.push_back({"child1", Child1});
```

so that I can save class template to create an object like this way:

```
Parent *obj = new v[0][1]();
```

which should work like this:

```
Parent *obj = new Child1();
```

I trid this:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, template<class T>>> v;
```

to add template to tuple.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Do you really mean tuple? Look like variant for me!

Comment: I'd say that you want to create a _Factory_ pattern, don't you? Types are not values in C++, but you can try with a static function.

Comment: @Klaus I have to use tuple because there're extra data to store

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks, I'll try it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't store a type directly. But you can store a function pointer, pointing to a function that constructs one of the derived classes when called.

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, Parent *(*)()>> v;
v.push_back({"Child1", []() -> Parent * {return new Child1;}});

Parent *ptr = std::get<1>(v[0])();
```

Here, `Parent *(*)()` means "pointer to a function with no parameters, returning `Parent *`".

`[]() -> Parent * {return new Child1;}` is a *lambda expression*, which is more or less an anonymous function. `()` indicates no parameters, and `-> Parent *` indicates that the return type is `Parent *`.

Note `std::get<1>(...)` instead of `...[1]`. The latter doesn't work on tuples. Note `()` at the end, which calls the function.

Since your tuple only has two elements, consider using a `std::pair<...>` instead. Then you could do `v[0].second` instead of `std::get<1>(v[0])`.

Since you seem to want to use the vector as a map from strings to functions, consider using an actual `std::map` instead of a vector.

---

Here's a full example using `std::map`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Parent
{
  public:
    virtual ~Parent() = default;
    virtual void foo() {std::cout << "Parent\n";}
};

class Child1 : public Parent
{
  public:
    void foo() override {std::cout << "Child1\n";}
};

class Child2 : public Parent
{
  public:
    void foo() override {std::cout << "Child2\n";}
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, Parent *(*)()> m;
    m.insert({"Child1", []() -> Parent * {return new Child1;}});

    Parent *ptr = m.at("Child1")();
    ptr->foo(); // Prints `Child1`.
}
```

Comment: I got an error:
cannot convert ‘Child1*’ to ‘Parent*’ in return
v.push_back({"Child1", []() -> Parent * {return new Child1;}});

Comment: @user12175383 Did you forget to inherit `Child` from `Parent`? I'll try to make a full example.

Comment: @user12175383 Here you go: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/91n7Px Also I added a better example (using `std::map`) to the answer itself.

Comment: Possible improvement: Return a `std::unique_ptr<Parent>` instead of a `Parent*`. Example:

`[]() -> std::unique_ptr<Parent> { return std::make_unique<Child1>(); }`
You'll have to adjust the `map` accordingly too.

Comment: @user12175383 [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yc4Gjv) of using `unique_ptr`s instead.